# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. cordova windows 10

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, package, windows-10-universal

Cordova win 10 App working fine.Now I am planning to create release mode package But while creating package i am getting these error(Debug mode creating package Successfully).could u please suggest me how to slove this error. 
Cordova version 6.1.1

Please find Error screenshort [Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS6hU.png)

Comment: What is your preference for win10 in your config.xml? I mean like <preference name="windows-phone-target-version" value="10.0" />

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to build for an unsupported architecture. Try to force x86/ARM build using the switch

```
 cordova build windows --prod --release --arch=x86
```

Comment: HI Eric,Build Successfully Generated debug Mode,Getting error in release Mode.

Comment: no Getting this error. error : The package Microsoft.CSharp wit
h version 4.0.1 could not be found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\. Run a NuGet package restore
 to download the package. [G:\sp16\myJobCard\myJobCard\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj

Comment: Well turns out you're missing a package. Did you run NuGet?

Comment: Now i am getting Same Error

Comment: Have you tried to delete bin obj folder and re-install the nuget package ?